# Jquery : how to get name of next element

Tags: jquery

I had written a  jquery code

```
   var next_element =$(this).next(); 
      alert("name="+next_element);
```

In a jquery event. But I got Ouput as `name=undifined` . why did it happens? if this is incorrect, how did i get the name of element next to the event happening ??

Comment: `next_element.attr('name')`

Comment: it is woriking thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#qew').click(function() {

  alert($(this).next().attr('name'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="qew">this</button>
<button name="that">that</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var next_element_name = $(this).next().attr('name');
alert("name=" + next_element_name);
```